# Increase Max prefix length for --log-prefix in iptables

Tags: iptables

I am using centos and iptables complains about the Max prefix length which is 29 for --log-prefix option.  How can I increase this limit?

Comment: I'm no expert but this looks: http://ftp.netfilter.org/pub/iptables/iptables-1.4.1-rc3/include/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_ULOG.h like that value is limited to 32: #define ULOG_PREFIX_LEN 32

Comment: Guess this would required recompiling iptables and mostly the kernel.  There is not way out without recompiling iptables?

Comment: Why not create yourself an index/lookup value for prefixes that map to your much longer string?

Comment: @davey: I was more looking for a direct solution which I am not aware than exploring a workaround.

Comment: More like 28 characters :/